# Spyder (IDE) image.show() program:

Tags: image-processing, spyder

How do I change which program runs when asking Spyder to showan image?

For instance when I run `image.show(), the image is opened with Windows Photos.

If it makes a difference, I'd prefer to open it in Photoshop. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Spyder is relying on Windows' default program to open the image.

See [Microsoft's documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028161/windows-10-change-default-programs) on how to configure default apps by file type. This case of OS configuration.

Comment: Thanks. Spyder asked me the first time around, but i just selected something.